# Is anyone using the ASP.NET MVC Framework on live sites?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications

Is it ready for that?

I've been playing with it for a short amount of time and it seems quite reasonable.  Is anyone using it for live sites?

any issues to be aware of?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) is.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, www.jobtree.com.au is. I also have another new site coming online in the next few days www.afterkickoff.com/football that is using it.

Answer (score 2):

http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/05/05/gallery-of-live-asp-net-mvc-sites.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think StackOverflow, itself, is built on ASP.NET MVC.  Just read this: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/09/15/stackoverflow-at-pdc.aspx

Answer (score 2):

We are using it on [Birmingham Museum and Art Gallery's Pre-Raphaelite collection online](http://www.preraphaelites.org) and we are really happy with the results.  Also using Silverlight deepzoom which we customised..

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at how to make ASP.NET MVC work on the specific version of IIS your're planning to use. There's a whole page on the topic (Using ASP.NET MVC with Different Versions of IIS) on http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-08-vb.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've been using ASP.NET MVC in production on several sites since Preview 2, and it has got  progressively better with each release.

One issue to be aware of with the latest release (Preview 5) is that there is a bug in the VirtualPathProviderViewEngine that can cause the wrong view to be rendered if you run in production mode (with <compilation debug="false" />). See [this post on the MVC forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1316297.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that asp.net MVC is built on top of a solid asp.net/.net foundation which is already well proven and you can mix the technologies if you choose. I've used it without any problems besides the learning curve.

My only note is that currently, 3rd party control vendors like Telerik, ComponentArt etc don't really work well with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow uses ASP.Net MVC. Seems to be doing pretty well here from my experience with the site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any completed sites written in ASP.NET MVC, but I have one in the works and a few others in mind that would be ideal in MVC.

The product is solid and you can expect to continue to see development in the coming months.  The only concern you should be aware of is that the code is likely going to change.  Though I'm sure that it's starting to stabilize, you should expect to update your code to accommodate those changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah we recently finished a site with MonoRail and have our own proprietary MVC framework for content generation too.

Answer (score 0):

We just deployed www.homespothq.com using ASP.NET MVC.  I am very pleased with how it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ASP.NET-MVC on a high volume private site and it has performed quite well. The separation of components with this architectural approach is very appealing.